# Copying an entire excel workbook to another workbook using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with 4 worksheets ("Initial Workbook").
I need to copy all four worksheets to a different workbook("New Workbook").

I have the below code which allows me to navigate to the Initial Workbook from the New Workbook and then copy a specific range on one worksheet.  I would like to amend this to allow me to select and copy all four of the worksheets on the Original Worksheet.

Any help you can provide would be most appreciated:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim wkbSourceBook As Workbook

    Dim rngSourceRange As Range
    Dim rngDestination As Range

    Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2002-03", "*.xls", 1
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa", 2
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show

        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
            Set wkbSourceBook = ActiveWorkbook
            Set rngSourceRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select source range", Title:="Source Range", Default:="$A:$CS", Type:=8)
            wkbCrntWorkBook.Activate
            Set rngDestination = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select destination cell", Title:="Select Destination", Default:="A1", Type:=8)
            rngSourceRange.Copy rngDestination
            rngDestination.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            wkbSourceBook.Close False
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

works like a charm:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Copy
```

(Source:http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/404450-visual-basic-applications-copy-active-workbook-new-workbook.html)

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, but the existing answers only copy Sheets (excluding Queries etc), and do so very inefficiently.  The below code works like a charm for me:

```
Function duplicateWorkbook(wk As Workbook) As Workbook
    Dim path As String
    path = Environ("temp") & "\" & wk.Name & "." & _ 
        Right(wk.FullName, Len(wk.FullName) - InStrRev(wk.FullName, "."))
    wk.SaveCopyAs path
    Set duplicateWorkbook = Workbooks.Add(path)
    Kill path
End Function
```

To use, simply call it as below:

```
Dim wk AS Workbook: Set wk = duplicateWorkbook(ActiveWorkbook)
```

The code saves a temporary copy of the workbook in the temp Folder, creates a new workbook using the temporary book as a template, and then deletes the temporary workbook.

Answer (score 2):

This reworked  code should copy your worksheets:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Dim wkbTarget As Workbook 'better use source and target as names, as its less confusing
    Dim strFileName As String

    Set wkbSource = ActiveWorkbook

    strFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        "Excel 2002-03 (*.xls), *.txt, " & _
        "Excel 2007 (*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa), *.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa")

    If strFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub 'make sure that your locale also returns False!

    Set wkbTarget = Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
    wkbSource.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")).Copy _
        Before:=wkbTarget.Sheets(1)
    'Further editing goes here

    wkbTarget.Close False

End Sub
```

Just replace the sheet names according to your needs.

(PS: You can find these commands yourself, if you simply record a macro where you copy the sheets to another workbook - and then look at the produced code! ;-) )

Comment: How about record a macro to "save as" the whole original workbook? Of course, you answer is more generic.

Comment: @Peter Albert.  I did try the macro recorder approach, but couldnt work out how to integrate it with the first half of the code i.e. navigating to the initial workbook.  I'm having the same problem with your suggested code above.  Where exactly shoudl I insert it, and which code should be deleted?  I assumed it would be this, but it trips up on your suggested code:

Comment: @PeterAlbert continuted from previous comment

        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
            wbkCrntWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")).Copy _
    Before:=wkbSourceBook.Sheets(1)
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Comment: @PeterAlbert THanks for the quick reply.  Unfortunately it trips at up at:
wkbSource.Sheets(Array("RATING", "EXPIRATING", "Options", "Claims")).Copy _
        Before:=wkbTarget.Sheets(1)

I have triple checked the spelling of the worksheets (including using a Macro recorder to obtain the names of the sheets) so I know the problem isn't there, but that's about all I DO know.

Comment: mmm, strange. Few questions: 1. Are you sure, that at the time of execution, `ActiveWorkbook` is the one with the 4 sheets? 2. Is the target file protected? 3. Does it work if you only copy one sheet with ` wkbSource.Sheets("RATING").Copy Before:=wkbTarget.Sheets(1)` 4. What is the error message?

Comment: @PeterAlbert I had a little tinker, and this works, but only if I specify the file name of the destination workbok:
         
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
            
        Sheets(Array("RATING", "EXPIRATING", "Options", "Claims")).Select
        Sheets(Array("RATING", "EXPIRATING", "Options", "Claims")).Copy Before:= _
        Workbooks("Import from global rater.xlsm").Sheets(1)
                End If
    End With

End Sub

Comment: Take a look at the code in the answer I updated earlier. I noticed you mixed up the workbooks in your original post and tried to fix this with the target/source naming...